# FindRoot does not gives the exact answer

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to find the intersection point of the solution of a set of ODEs with a small cut-off. We set the domain of integration of ODEs to be `[0,end]` but `FindRoot` gives the crosses point far from the end point. You can see more and accurate details in the following code

```
eqs[z0_] := {D[
  z[x]^(2 (1 - \[Xi])) F[v[x], z[x]] v'[x] + 
   z[x]^(1 - \[Xi])  z'[x], x] - 
 z[x]^(2 (1 - \[Xi])) D[F[v[x], z[x]], v[x]] v'[x]^2/2 == 0, 
D[z[x]^(1 - \[Xi]) v'[x], x] - 
 d\[Theta]/z[x] (z0/z[x])^(2 d\[Theta]) - 
 z[x]^(2 (1 - \[Xi])) D[F[v[x], z[x]], z[x]] v'[x]^2/
  2 - (1 - \[Xi]) z[
   x]^-\[Xi] (z'[x] + z[x]^(1 - \[Xi]) F[v[x], z[x]] v'[x]) v'[
   x] == 0};
F[v_, z_] := 1 - M[v] z^(d\[Theta] + \[Xi]);
M[v_] := 1/2 (1 + Tanh[v/a]);
d\[Theta] = d - \[Theta]; \[Theta] = 2/3; \
[Xi] = 1.5; d = 2; a = 0.5;

Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];

extsurf[t0_, z0_, L_] := Block[{sol, end, cut},
  sol = NDSolve[
  Join[eqs[z0], {v[0] == t0, z[0] == z0, v'[0] == 0, 
   z'[0] == 0}], {v, z}, {x, 0, L/2}, MaxSteps -> Infinity,
    Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> 10^-5 < z[x] <= z0, 
   "EventAction" -> "StopIntegration"}][[1]];
  end = InterpolatingFunctionDomain[First[z /. sol]][[1, -1, 2]];
  cut = FindRoot[Evaluate[z[x] /. sol] - 0.2 == 0, {x, 0}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 50, AccuracyGoal -> 50][[1, 2]];
  {end, z[end] /. sol, cut, 
  NIntegrate[
  Evaluate[z0^d\[Theta]/z[x]^(2 d\[Theta]) /. sol], {x, 0, cut}], 
  Plot[{0.2, {z[x] /. sol}}, {x, 0, end}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, end}, {0, 1}}]}]
```

For Example, `extsurf[-6, 4.71879, 8]` gives the results below:
`4. , 0.11945 , 4.0008730 , 50.6728`

My main questions are

1) Despite the fact that the maximum value of `NDSolve` is `4`- why `FindRoot` goes beyond that value (`4.0008730`)??

2) When the first guess is changed e.g. `3`, i can get the desired result which is less than `4`. In the other words,the desired result is dependent on the first guess! Why this happens?

Comment: 1) When `InterpolationFunction` is given an argument outside its domain, it often uses extrapolation to provide a value.  2) Your function may have more than one zero.

Comment: the Plot of configuration shows one zero in domain `[0,end]`.

Comment: `extsurf[-6, 4.71879, 8]` produces numerous error messages.  You should not expect a correct answer under such circumstances.

Comment: Also, `FindRoot` is searching beyond `end`, because you have not told it to do otherwise.

Comment: Instead of using `FindRoot` I'd recommend you put a `WhenEvent` in `NDSolve` to cause the solver to find the point where `z[x]=0.2`  That way `NDSolve` will adjust its incrementaiotn and find that for you much more accurately. A bit aside but whats to point of asking for high precision from `FindRoot` when the `NDSolve` result is machine precision?

Comment: as another matter since you have told `NDSolve` to stop when `z` falls below `z0` (4.7) then `z[x]=.2` will always be some garbage extrapolated outside the solution domain.

Comment: @george2079 I added the line `Reap@NDSolve[
  Join[eqs[z0new], {v[0] == t0, z[0] == z0new, v'[0] == 0, z'[0] == 0,
     WhenEvent[{5 10^-4 < z[x] < z0new, z[x] == 0.2}, {cut = Sow[x]; 
      "StopIntegration"}]}], {v, z}, {x, 0, L/2}, 
  MaxSteps -> Infinity]` But the obtained results is extremely small! why this happens?

Comment: you should have two separate `WhenEvent` s, one for the stop condition, one for the `z=.2`.  The stop condition should be i think `z<5 10^-4 || z>z0` btw.